# how to normalize fft values for neural networks

Tags: neural-network, fft, normalization, librosa

I calculate the fft for a given soundfile and get an array of the shape e.g. (100,257) with 100 rows and 257 frequency bins. I want to use this as an input vector for a neural network but before I want to normalize with librosa lib

https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.util.normalize.html#librosa.util.normalize

so should I normalize over axis=0 or axis=1? axis=0 normalizes the columns aggregated over the rows and axis=1 normalizes every row or should I normalize over every value independent of rows and columns?

Answer (score 0):

The way how you normalize the fft depends on your application and the final performance. There isn't a general normalization scheme.

In one of my application, I didn't normalize and input the raw fft to the neural network. One common way to normalize is taking the logarithm. This operation can reduce the dynamic range.